# com.facebook.react.JavaScript (17): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xda9bf7c08)

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, xcode9.2

**Environment:**

```
OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.6
Xcode: Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
Node: 6.11.1
npm: 3.10.10
Watchman: 4.9.0
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

**Description:**

When I run my code the app gets crashes in this line ***`context = [JSC_JSContext(contextRef) contextWithJSGlobalContextRef:contextRef]`*** which is from /Users/mac1/Documents/test/project/node_modules/react-native/React/Executors/RCTJSCExecutor.mm. Can anyone help me with this issue???

I have attached the crashlytics log with this.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nz00ys2reh69k4w/crashlytics_log.txt?dl=0

Comment: How did you solve this?